# How can I run command prompt command from c# windows application?

Tags: c#, cmd

I run this command in windows command:

```
dtexec /f package.dtsx
```

wan't to run that command in windows app,more explain want to write windows application to run command prompt and in the command prompt run that command,how can i write code for that purpose?thank's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `System.Diagnostics.Process`

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe","/C dtexec /f package.dtsx");
```

Comment: thanks for help,my friend mr Vali run that code,and say's just show me cmd and do not run dtexec command.

Comment: what this command actually do ?

Comment: Add /c before dtexec i.e. "/c dtexec /f package.dtsx"

Comment: write this             System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "mkdir e:\behiii");
and don't make directory so

Comment: check update it should work now

Comment: my friend i wrote System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/C mkdir e:/sample");,so why can't create run command prompt ,command

Comment: you have used forward slash you need to use back slash `mkdir e:\sample`

Comment: make the command `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/C mkdir e:\\sample");`

Answer (score -1):

You can use like this code-

```
        string strCmdText;
        strCmdText = "/C Dir";
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
```

This code will work to run cmd command using C#.